# User registration using django and backbone over a RESTful API

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-applications, backbone.js

I'm building a simple application as part of my learning(to understand REST APIs) using django and backbone. I would like to create a user registration and pass these values to django backend using json. Can someone point me to some examples and source codes to construct good APIs using django and using them with backbone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say [this is a good example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-3-deep-linking-and-application-states/), where he's creating new wines with a model.set over a JSON api.

For example... take a look at the section with:

```
saveWine:function () {
        this.model.set({
            name:$('#name').val(),
            grapes:$('#grapes').val(),
            country:$('#country').val(),
            region:$('#region').val(),
            year:$('#year').val(),
            description:$('#description').val()
        });
        if (this.model.isNew()) {
            var self = this;
            app.wineList.create(this.model, {
                success:function () {
                    app.navigate('wines/' + self.model.id, false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.model.save();
        }

        return false;
```

Comment: the model.save() method will trigger that url associated with that model right? can I do something like this in my model `url: localhost/users` and calling `collection.fetch()`? Assuming that it would return a json with list of users. Is this correct?

Comment: It should trigger the save on the associated model. If you take a look at the tutorial, (the link is for part 3), he goes over a pretty good example of passing in the model to the view, and then posting to the JSON api via the model.set

Answer (score 1):

For APIs, look at [django-tastypie](http://tastypieapi.org/) and [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/). Those are a couple of REST API frameworks I found active and well designed.

Answer (score 1):

You need a REST backend in your django application in order to communicate with backbone. 
Django views are built to respond with html but they can also respond with json.
I wouldn't recommend trying to build your own json views though, but rather use something like django-tastypie

Comment: I'm using windows. Is there a way to add tastypie via a package manager in django or python?

Comment: pip install django-tastypie

Comment: Just in case. http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/